# Go works from command line, but not from IntelliJ Idea Go

Tags: intellij-idea, go

Under Mac OS X I did a brew install go. I also downloaded the Go IntelliJ IDE from here

```
http://go-ide.com/2011/08/09/goide_release_1_0_darwin.html
```

The following program compiles and runs fine from the command line, but if I use the GO IntelliJ IDE it gives an error:

```
can't find import: math/rand
```

import time seems ok, but Duration and time.Millisecond are undefined. If I remove these things and just run the "Hello World version" the program compiles and runs fine.

```
/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: idf
 * Date: 4/2/14
 * Time: 1:59 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */

package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "math/rand" /* causes problems */
  "time"
)

func main() {

    sleep := time.Duration(200) /* error: undefined: time.Duration */
    time.Sleep(sleep * time.Millisecond) /* error: undefined: time.Millisecond */


    rand.Intn(1000)

    fmt.Println("Hello World")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Updated:*
You'll need to add your GOROOT and GOPATH:
https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/blob/master/Missing%20ENV.md

*the exact commands I ran (obviously, your GOPATH and GOROOT will be different):*

```
launchctl setenv GOPATH /Users/wfreeman/gocode
launchctl setenv GOROOT /Users/wfreeman/go1.2
```

Comment: I am confused by your response. If it can find fmt, and time, why would adding these paths help? Intellisense shows me several things when I type the dot after time, but Duration nor milliseconds are not there. I tried what you suggested anyway, and see no difference.

Comment: It appears that the go that brew installs and the one in the IDE are not the same. if I say from a command prompt, "which go", it gives /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2/bin and there is a whole structure in there. The IDE one is pointing to packages /Applications/Go Ide.app/bundle ... I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Did you restart intellij after making those changes? It worked for me.

Comment: You should use the GOROOT from brew (/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2).